# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NativeDetector Error while running IT cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm working on something which required Integration test cases, and unit test cases. When I'm trying to run the test cases, junit are running but IT cases (classIT.java) are failing with error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NativeDetector.

Comment: How you are executing test cases?, also do you mean only unit tests for one specific class is failing?

Comment: By directly running the test class or by doing clean install

Comment: right click on this class's unit test class & do run as junit, let us know if it works?

Comment: yes it was running as a junit only